# Доступ к классам из любого места

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть ли возможность в PHP соединить все классы и обращаться к ним из любого места? Т.е. чтобы любой класс был доступен из любого места.

Comment: Все классы подключить в одном файле, например `autoloader.php`

Answer (score 3):

Добрый вечер.
Используйте автозагрузку с помощью composer.
Можно сделать [так](http://klisl.com/composer_autoload.html).

Answer (score 2):

Кроме Composer, можете использовать встроенные механизмы PHP
[Автозагрузчик PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)